# Printing a PDF in an iFrame from the parent frame in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, printing

So I have a main document which contains an iFrame, in which is a PDF file, which contains a barcode (Created by iTextSharp and sized for a Dymo Label printer).

HTML looks something like:

```
<html>
    <body>
       <div class="content">
           <iframe src="/pdfs/label.pdf" NAME="loyaltyBadge" ID="loyaltyBadge"></iframe>
               <br/>
           <button id="printPdf">Print</button>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Using jQuery or standard JS, how can I make the button trigger the print dialog on the PDF frame?

This:

```
$('#printPdf').click(function () {
    document.loyaltyBadge.print();
});
```

Seems to work in Chrome, but not FF where I get an error `document.loyaltyBadge is undefined`

I've tried Googling, but most results are people giving suggests where the document in the iFrame is HTML so we can put the print control in the iFrame itself, which of course in this case I can't do.

The iFrame is small so the native Print control from the embeded Adobe Reader is no use.